# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia Error "DOMException"

Tags: javascript, audio, mediarecorder, mediadevices

> Microphone permission granted.

I get the error "DOMException" without any detailed description when I try to run this code `await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})`.

Even in console< when I run this code `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.error(e));` 
I get an error "DOMException".

Why does this happen, what do I need to do?

*Js, Vue.js, Chrome, MacOS Mojave.*

[example in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyXz1.png)

Comment: Hi! Can you give more information about this exception?
[DOMException](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException) should have properties `code`, `message` and [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException#Error_names).      
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Exceptions) is list of possible DOM exceptions

Comment: The fact of the matter is that there is an error without information, and this is strange.

Comment: Look at  “example in console” image.  One more thing, everything works fine on my home computer. And previously worked on a working PC. I don’t know what happened.

Comment: Just throwing my hat into the ring here. I'm seeing identical behaviour in Chrome 75.0.3770.100 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132). It's not consistent between machines, however. I've tested on two machines running those versions of Chrome and MacOS. One works as expected, one throws the DOMException with no additional information. The same thing happens regardless of whether I use `getUserMedia` or `webkitGetUserMedia`.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS Mojave has specific permissions for the camera in System Preferences. I was running into the same problem until I granted Chrome permission to use the camera. (same for audio)

Comment: System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Camera / Checkbox next to "Chrome"